# How to change this jQuery widget (written for jQueryUI 1.7) so that it works with jQueryUI 1.8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, widget, jquery-widgets

[This jQuery plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/h8vnw/), which lets users draw rectangles in a div, works with jQueryUI 1.7.2.

I need to get it working with [jQueryUI 1.8.4](http://jsfiddle.net/YdRpG/). From reading the [widget upgrade guide](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Upgrade_Guide), I can't work out what needs to change. I tried renaming _init() to _create(), but that didn't do anything. What else do I need to change to get it working? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$.widget` signature changed to do the extend internally, so change this:

```
$.widget("ui.boxer", $.extend({}, $.ui.mouse, {
```

To this:

```
$.widget("ui.boxer", $.ui.mouse, {
```

And at the bottom, remove the extra `)` as well, changing `}));` to `});`

---

Also, to get the default options, it's best to move them right inside, like this:

```
$.widget("ui.boxer", $.ui.mouse, {
  options: {
    appendTo: 'body',
    distance: 0
  },
  ///rest of widget, unchanged...
});
```

[Here's a sample of the updated version with *only* the changes above](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/h8vnw/3/), working.