# Categories in old version of jQueryUI AutoComplete control

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm stuck on jQuery 1.7 and jQueryUI 1.8.6, and currently unable to upgrade (we have quite a bit of deprecated and removed code, and can't upgrade at this time).

I can use [jQueryUI's AutoComplete control](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), but I'm unable to figure out how to use categories - using the sample [found here](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories).

```
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function() {
      this._super();
      this.widget().menu( "option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)" );
    },
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
      var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
      $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
        var li;
        if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
          ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
          currentCategory = item.category;
        }
        li = that._renderItemData( ul, item );
        if ( item.category ) {
          li.attr( "aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label );
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

I get an error: `this._super is not a function`, and if I remove that line, then the following line fails when calling `widget()`, with `Cannot read property 'element' of undefined`.

I know the syntax for jQuery plugins changed between versions, but I can't seem to modify their sample so that it will work with the older versions. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310189/how-to-change-this-jquery-widget-written-for-jqueryui-1-7-so-that-it-works-wit) hinted toward a slightly different syntax back in 1.7, but I just kept getting different errors as I fiddled with it.

Any idea what I need to change to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_super` method was created in newer versions of jQuery UI, and it doesn't exist in previous versions. As a workaround, you can call `$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._create.call(this);` that will basically do the same as `_super` does.

---

As soon as the `_renderItemData` didn't exit either, you must implement it, by changing it to `_renderItem` and then calling `.data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item );`

Your complete code changed would be:

```
$.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
  _create: function () {
    $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._create.call(this);
    this.widget().menu("option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)");
  },
  _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
    var that = this,
      currentCategory = "";
    $.each(items, function (index, item) {
      var li;
      if (item.category != currentCategory) {
        ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
        currentCategory = item.category;
      }
      li = that._renderItem(ul, item).data('ui-autocomplete-item', item);
      if (item.category) {
        li.attr("aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Fiddle working: http://jsfiddle.net/qjw165sz/1/